# Continuous function and periodic

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, terminology, periodic-functions

A function $f: X\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is periodic when exist $p \in (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that all continuous and periodic functions $f: X\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are bounded and reach the maximum and minimum values. 
The result is valid if $f: X\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is countinuous and periodic?

I really don't know where I can start. The hint of the book tells me: Take $x_0, x_1 \in [0,p]$ points where $f|_{\{0,p\}}$ reach the maximum and minimum values. And the answer of question is satisfied with the proof of this?

Comment: Do you know the extreme value theorem?

Comment: Yes. That can help me? @ma

Comment: As a hint, you want to find a way to apply the EVT.  That's a little tricky though, as it's only valid for compact subsets (closed and bounded, or of the form $[a,b]$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$).  You'll need to find a good one to look at, apply it, and argue why this tells you something about $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Bella Patarroyo Please check your statement. In order to prove that $f$ is bounded we need some hypothesis for $X$.

Comment: This is a exercises of Análisis real by Elon Lages Lima. Chapter 7, section 3 exercise 4. This is the book: https://vargasmat.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/anc3a1lisis-real-lima.pdf  
I don't find the english book, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $X=\mathbb{R}$ then the property is true. Since $f$ is continuous and the interval $[0,p]$ is closed and bounded, it follows that $f$ attains in $[0,p]$ a maximum and a minimum value, by the [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). Moreover, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ let $k:=\lfloor x/p \rfloor\in\mathbb{Z}$, then  $t:=x-kp\in [0,p]$ and
$$f(x)=f(x-kp)=f(t).$$
Can you take it from here?

Note that $f(x)=\tan(x)$ is a periodic and continuous function in $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\pi/2+k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$, which is NOT bounded.